# Activate location for "Find my Device"

Tags: geolocation, location-services

When I go to https://www.google.com/android/find?u=0 (Find my Device), it says "Online" and "Location Turned Off" (under the device name) and the device is not located on the map.

I have checked the following on the device:

- Settings->Security & Location->Find My Device: is "On"
- Settings->Security & Location->Location->Use Location: is "On"
- Wifi and mobile data are on (I have Internet connection)
- The device knows its location (in Google Maps)
- Find My Device can make my phone ring remotely.

Note: Sometimes the map shows the device (and the message becomes "Last seen ...") but this happens only rarely and under unpredictable circumstances (and a reload of the webpage makes it go back to "Location Turned Off" even if the phone was not moved and no settings were changed).

My device is an Umidigi A5 Pro with Android 9.

Comment: are you using same account?

Comment: @rajkavadia Yes. Find My Device successfully sees the phone ("Online") and I can make it ring. I just cannot get the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to enabling location services, the "battery saver" mode must be off.

In battery saver mode, location services will be automatically deactivated when the screen is off ([Android Help](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079240?hl=en)). Unfortunately, Find My Device is not clever enough to deactivate batter saver mode for determining the location.

I did not find a way to use Find My Device while at the same time being able to extend battery life.

Comment: I am not going to argue about your answer, it is correct, but "Battery Saver" isn't really intended to extend battery life, it is to keep the device minimally usable if the battery level falls below a certain level or is likely (base on previous usage) to run out before the next typical charge and should not be active all the time under normal use. Things like Adaptive Battery are intended to help minimize battery usage during day to day use to extend battery life. If your device isn't meeting your battery life needs, maybe look into why it isn't with a tool like GSAM Battery Monitor?

Comment: @acejavelin That doesn't really make sense to me... If the battery saver reduces battery consumption on an almost empty battery, then it stands to reason that it also reduces battery consumption when the batter is still full. Of course, there is a tradeoff (reduction of background features such as synching) but I'm happy with that if it gives a day or two extra battery life.

And even if one does not want the battery saver on the whole time, I think the inability to locate the phone is still a serious problem because one might lose the phone while having low battery.